Microsoft.ML C# properties of internal input class must be public otherwise error
I'm working on an ML.NET project where I load data into an IDataView, apply an ONNX model transformation, and then access the transformed output.
My Input class is in the same assembly as my Output class and as my Model class. I mark my Input class as internal. I mark my Input class properties as internal and I have an error. When I mark my properties as public (class is still internal), it works.
I thought if the class was marked as internal, there would be no difference if the properties/methods are internal or public (quote: "a public member of an internal class is effectively internal."). Clearly it does.
Here is a Minimal Reproducible Example:
using Microsoft.ML;
using Microsoft.ML.Data;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    internal class InputData
    {
        [ColumnName("onnx::Concat_0")]
        [VectorType(342)]
        // public float[] XA1 { get; set; } = new float[342];  // Works

        internal float[] XA1 { get; set; } = new float[342]; // Fails
    }

    public class OutputData
    {
        [ColumnName("onnx::Concat_0")]
        [VectorType(342)]
        public float[] XA1 { get; set; }
    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            var mlContext = new MLContext();

            var inputData = new[]
            {
                new InputData { XA1 = new float[342] }
            };

            IDataView inputDataView = mlContext.Data.LoadFromEnumerable(inputData);

            // Simulate an ONNX transformation pipeline
            var pipeline = mlContext.Transforms.CopyColumns(
                "onnx::Concat_0",
                "onnx::Concat_0"
            );

            var model = pipeline.Fit(inputDataView);
            IDataView transformedData = model.Transform(inputDataView);

            var transformed = mlContext.Data.CreateEnumerable<OutputData>(transformedData, reuseRowObject: false);
            foreach (var item in transformed)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"XA1 Length: {item.XA1.Length}");
            }
        }
    }
}

In case that helps:

I am using net8.0.
I am using JetBrains Rider 2024.2.6.


I don't know the details since i dont know the lib but the reason is pretty simple the pipline.fit Method cannot access the property since its internal. You can enable debugging and see in detail when this is happening.

I see, but does that mean that the answer in the link I highlighted is actually not correct? An internal class can have public and internal members and their behaviour will differ?

Ah now i get where this is going... Well there has to be a difference in this concrete example. But i have no idea what ml.net is doing with the properties.

the problem is that the IDataView inputDataView = mlContext.Data.LoadFromEnumerable(inputData); does not have a schema if the property is internal. Which than causes the error on pipeline.Fit(inputDataView);

This seems to be very specific to ml.net

So there are (rare) instances where having an internal class with public methods/properties is different than an internal class with internal methods/properties? Is this desired or more on the bug side? I’m a beginner so the questions might seem stupid, sorry.

Indeed in a "normal" context, there's no difference between an internal and a public member of an interal type, however in a reflection context, there is and this is what causes this behaviour.
If you navigate1 in ML.NET's code, when you do mlContext.Data.LoadFromEnumerable(inputData);, ML.NET builds up informations about your class's fields and properties inside SchemaDefinition.GetMemberInfos(Type, Direction), here's the relevant code inside it:
var fieldInfos = userType.GetFields(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance);
var propertyInfos = userType.GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance)
    ...

Here you can see they use BindingFlags.Public, which means take only public properties/fields. If they wanted to process internal (or rather, all non-public) properties/fields they'd have used BindingFlags.NonPublic (or BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic if they wanted both public and non-public).
This kind of reflection based operations typically only care about public members because, as the accepted answer to the question you linked says, non-public members are implementation details.
When you do pipeline.Fit(inputDataView) it looks for the property with [ColumnName("onnx::Concat_0")], but since it didn't process your internal property, it finds none and throws that exception.

1 The whole path from your call to LoadFromEnumerable to the code doing reflection is:

DataOperationsCatalog.LoadFromEnumerable<TRow>(IEnumerable<TRow>, SchemaDefinition)
DataViewConstructionUtils.CreateFromEnumerable<TRow>(IHostEnvironment, IEnumerable<TRow>, SchemaDefinition)
InternalSchemaDefinition.Create(Type, SchemaDefinition.Direction)
SchemaDefinition.Create(Type, Direction)
SchemaDefinition.GetMemberInfos(Type, Direction)


